# The => and comma operators in a Perl system call

Tags: perl

I'm a complete beginner in Perl, so please bear with me if my question is trivial.

I am trying to fix a bug in a rather large Perl project. By some trial and error and print statements I could figure out that the following system call to imagemagick is responsible for the bug:

```
system(
    composite => $tmpfilename,
    -gravity => $gravity_combo->get_active_text,
    $filename => $tmpfilename2
);
```

The code exectution just stops at this system call and emits no output. By chance, when trying to get some output from this system call, I discovered that if I substitute the system call by the following

```
my $command = "composite " . $tmpfilename . " -gravity " . $gravity_combo->get_active_text . " " . $filename . " " . $tmpfilename2;

my $output = `$command`;
```

the command is executed successfully.

As you can see, the commas and => arrows are substituted by string concatenation and system() is substituted by the backticks, but other than that the commands are identical.

Now I wonder how this happened and if there is a more elegant way to write the command in a working way.

Addendum:

I didn't want to share the complete code because, on one hand, it is the code of a somewhat popular app and I didn't want to give the impression that dilettantes like myself are working on it (I'm not the developer anyway, just a team member dealing mostly with user support on the bug tracker); on the other hand I didn't expect more context to be helpful in this case. But as several users requested more context, and also the problem seems to be more involved than I initially assumed, I will provide the complete code.

The code in question is from a plugin for the screenshot tool Shutter for the Linux desktop. The whole project can be found at https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter, the specific plugin in question is at https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/blob/master/share/shutter/resources/system/plugins/perl/spwatermark/spwatermark

When launching the plugin a dialog is shown where the user can enter some fields. The dialog looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the plugin dialog]

When first launching it, it executes the function `fct_imagemagick_watermark()` (which starts in line 254). Whenever the refresh or save button is clicked, a signal is sent which relaunches this function (the signals are sent in lines 164 and 167). Inside the function, a subfunction `apply_effect()` is called which starts at line 341 and includes two system calls to imagemagick commands in lines 354 and 365. Actually, both system calls fail when the function is called via refresh or save button, but the commands work if they are written using backticks and concatenation dots.

`$gravity_combo->get_active_text` is the value of the dropdown menu in the upper right corner of the dialog (for example, "Center"). The two tmpfilename variables are generated around line 227, the filename variable comes from the main program.

That's how far I could understand the code so far, please ask again, if there are further questions!

Addendum 2: Possible values for the variables in the system call from the original question:

```
$tmpfile = /tmp/euQgBTRpnf.png
$tmpfile2 = /tmp/eftbUp8eNf.png
$filename = /home/user/myimage.png
$gravity_combo = Gtk3::ComboBoxText=HASH(0x55e315db9568)
$gravity_combo->get_active-text = "Center"
```

Comment: What OS? Does `composite` output anything to be captured in `$output`? You should check the return value of [system](https://perldoc.pl/system).

Comment: `system` does not capture any output, unlike backticks (or `qx()` which is the same thing). It should however do the same command in the shell, which may have some effect outside Perl. Presumably that is not the source of the bug, since, as you say, the commands are identical. What is the bug?

Comment: Try `system('composite',  $tmpfilename, '-gravity', $gravity_combo->get_active_text, $filename, $tmpfilename2);` instead.

Comment: @choroba: Linux (Arch Linux to be more precise).

Comment: @TLP: It is a GUI app which in particular has a "refresh" and a "save" button. When first launched it executes a function which includes this system call, this works successfully. But when I click on the "refresh" or "save" button", which should again launch the function, the action isn't executed and the GUI is closed. I tracked it down with print statements (the print statement right before the system call is executed, the one afterwards isn't when one of the buttons is clicked; on initial launch both are executed).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Still gives the bug, unfortunately!

Comment: @Photon It is unlikely that we have enough information to help you solve this problem. If the system call does not return, do you mean to say that your Perl program hangs, or dies? Technically, the only way `print 1; system(..); print 2` does not perform both prints is if `system` hangs, or the Perl code somehow exits (which is unlikely, since system is executed in a fork). Have you read the documentation for system? https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system

Comment: Also: https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick

Comment: @TLP Regarding Image::Magick, I know that it exists so the system call can most probably be replaced by Image::Magick commands, I just wanted to get this thing fixed in the least invasive way, since I just started dealing with Perl today and don't feel confident enough to make bigger changes. Regarding the system documentation, thanks for the link, should be the first hit in the Google search but it wasn't for some reason... Looks like there are chances to get some output from a system call in the end! I will try and report back asap.

Comment: @TLP: It says "child exited with value 0", what can we conclude from this?

Comment: @Photon What did you do to get that message? I think 0 exit value means success, but that message seems to indicate some failure. From what I can glean at imagemagicks webpage, "composite" is a command to overlay images on top of each other, like a stand-alone command. Maybe it triggers the core program, which then exits after the command is performed.

Comment: @TLP I did this: https://pastebin.com/wfMsxQt2 (basically copy&paste from the system documentation that you linked). Exactly, composite should overlay two images but this does not happen if the bug kicks in.

Comment: Another thing maybe worth mentioning is that the system call used to work some years ago (maybe around 8 years) but got broken, most probably, due to Perl updates. Looks like something has changed at some point in Perl...

Comment: Oh I see, it is just some debugging code. It means the command was executed, I would guess (though it may not have been successful). This sort of thing is very hard to debug. The reason your Perl program is no longer working is likely because the Imagemagick binaries have started working slightly different, and you have no API that is up to date to handle that. If the code had been written with a Perl module, you would not be having this problem. It can also be something like that your GUI has file lock on your image file, or that it relies on "composite" command being in a specific dir.

Comment: @TLP But the funny thing is that it works, if dots and backticks are used instead of the system call and arrows&commas. If the composite command was in the wrong dir, it wouldn't work in any case!

Comment: Try using `Data::Dumper` to print the arguments to the `system` command and the backtick command, and see exactly what is in the commands. `system` can be done with a single string as well, but the list method is safer. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@args`  (put the arguments in `@args` array first)

Comment: @TLP I fear, I need to leave for now but I will try Data::Dumper tomorrow and report back, thanks!

Comment: `IDENT =>` is the same as `"IDENT",`, plain and simple.

Comment: YOu provided highly incomplete code. You also need to provide the values for which the problem manifests itself. OS too

Comment: @ikegami I added additional context via editing the original question.

Comment: @Photon yet you still don't provide any of the values?!?

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, missed that, I added some now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't enough information to answer fully but we can explain the difference.   It is two-fold.

First, there is that apparent and simple ["fat comma"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator) asked about

> The `=>` operator (sometimes pronounced "fat comma") is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores. This includes operands that might otherwise be interpreted as operators, constants, single number v-strings or function calls.

So, the word on its left gets (double) quoted, simply and crudely put -- where some characters or strings which otherwise may be treated as operators or functions now aren't. That shouldn't be of significance since there's only the `$filename` which is a variable and *that* should be clear.

Then the fat-comma based line is a simle list

```
system( 
    "composite", $tmpfilename, 
    "-gravity", $gravity_combo->get_active_text, 
    $filename, $tmpfilename2
);
```

(that `$filename` gets interpolated anyway so I left out the unneeded quotes)

The second difference is subtler and far more loaded: when you give `system` a list, it doesn't invoke the shell but uses a system call directly, whereby the first argument is the command name and others are passed to that command as its arguments.

The other way to run the command, that you found to work, is different: The [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) (backticks) forms a string of whatever is passed to it, scans it for shell metacharacters and if any are found passes it to the shell for execution.<sup>†</sup> There may be subtle variations but mostly that's what it does. That may well be very different.

So an obvious guess is that something in there needs the shell, which it gets in the backticks (`qx`) approach but not with a list under `system`.  One way to test that is to force a shell on this

```
system('bash', '-c', "composite $tmpfilename ...");
```

(or, concatenate with spaces: `join(' ', 'composite', $tmpfilename, ...)` like you do)

It may even be that the `composite` command itself needs to be run out of a shell, due to some environment details or such. (Since from links in comments it appears that the rest of arguments are plain numbers or strings and filenames.) This is just a simple guess.

Really we'd need to see details, but hopefully this helps some.

---

<sup>†</sup> While you compose the command as a string anyway, so even if that were then passed to the `system` it would be treated the same way.

Comment: Thanks! I added additional context to the question, as it seems to be incomplete otherwise.

Comment: @Photon I can't be more definitive since your application is complex and I can't test, but I hope that this helps you out.  Edited my answer to add the above comment.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately, it doesn't work out. I get a long output of imagemagick options which usually comes if you run `composite` without any options. So it looks like `bash -c` only takes the directly following string as argument and ignores the rest.

Comment: @Photon Yes, of course; been too long since I last dealt with this.  Need the 'rest" (command to run out of the shell) as one string, so `system('bash', '-c', "composite ...");` (double quotes so to interpolate variables etc).  Editing the answer...

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong, it complains about not finding one of the tempfiles, directly at launch. I will try to figure out what is going on tomorrow!

Comment: I just ended up using the original workaround I posted in the original question, still don't understand what was going on, but that's fine. :)

Comment: @Photon Alright, that was clear and good from the beginning, that you had a working solution all along :)  As for what is going on, what the question was about, I think that I explain all difference between the two cases as presented -- as much as possible, since not many details are available.  In the end, also remember that there are a number of good modules for running external commands.

Comment: I couldn't verify the hypothesis unfortunately, and I fear, it wouldn't be an easy task to do so, as my attempts so far failed. But never mind, a working solution is there, and I think, I won't become a Perl developer anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just space out the args like this:

```
my $cmd =" composite   $tempfilename
          -gravity     $gravity_combo->get_active_text
          $filename   $tmpfilename2)
         ";
$cmd =~ tr/\n//d; 
$result = `$cmd`;
```

The => is also called the "fat comma" and is normally used in hash structures, but that is not what you have here.

Ok, I see now. "$gravity_combo->get_active_text" is an executable function.
It will not execute if it is within quotes.
Does this work?

```
my $cmd = " composite ".    $tempfilename.
          " -gravity  ".    $gravity_combo->get_active_text().
          " $filename ".    $tmpfilename2;
```

---

Ok, I've been watching the comments.  I've gone back to the original question and implemented a gravity object so that the calling syntax works.  When I call foo() below instead of system(), it looks like it "works" and this string returned should also work in a system call. Consider this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tmpfilename = "temp";
my $filename = "somefile";
my $tmpfilename2 = "temp2";

package Gravity;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $me =  {};

    bless($me, $class);

    $me ->{active_text} = "ABC";
    return $me;
}

sub get_active_text
{
   my $me = shift;
   return $me->{active_text};
}

my $gravity_combo = new Gravity;

## call foo() instead of system() and see what it prints...

foo (
    composite => $tmpfilename,
    -gravity => $gravity_combo->get_active_text,
    $filename => $tmpfilename2
);

sub foo
{
    print "@_\n"; #system ("@_"); should work?
}

# prints: composite temp -gravity ABC somefile temp2
```

From what I can tell here, make a helper func like foo() and have it make a string to pass to the system call. It looks like this prevents getting bogged down into quoting rules. The args to foo() above look "pretty" (nicely formatted as per the original question and pleasing at least to my eye).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it then doesn't resolve `$gravity_combo->get_active_text` properly. It substitutes $gravity_combo correctly, but doesn't access the get_active_text property.

Comment: The version of the answer after the edit is actually what I did, I was just wondering if there is a more elegant way, and also why it fails the original way (the system call). Edit: Ok, not exactly the same, I used the dot for concatenation, I think, it doesn't work with just one big string because of resolving $gravity_combo->get_active_text as well. It literally substitutes "Gtk3::ComboBoxText=HASH(0x55e315db9568)->get_active_text" instead of the actual text without the dots.

Comment: Regarding the latest edit, it says `Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at ... ` and fails to execute the command, as far as I understand.

Comment: You cannot use a comma separated list in scalar assignment. The first item in the list will be assigned, and the rest of the list will be discarded (void context). The error means you concatenate 2 things, then throw them away.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I wrote some more code to show how the original question's syntax can work with a "helper" function, which I called foo().  I didn't delete any previous mistakes on my part, I left those lines,  warts and all.  My latest code looks like a solution to me.

Comment: I just ended up using the original workaround I posted in the original question, still don't understand what was going on, but that's fine. :)